# Как отследить появление элемента на экране и получить его id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем добрый день! Нашел в интернете функцию отслеживания появление блока на экране по классу. Но вопрос такой у меня несколько таких блоков, и необходимо получить id показываемого блока в данный момент. Буду рад если кто-то поможет! Спасибо!

```js
var block_show = null;

function scrollTracking() {
  var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
  var wh = $(window).height();
  var et = $('.active').offset().top;
  var eh = $('.active').outerHeight();

  if(wt + wh >= et && wt + wh - eh * 2 <= et + (wh - eh)) {
    if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
      console.log('Блок active в области видимости');
    }
    block_show = true;
  } else {
    if(block_show == null || block_show == true) {
      console.log('Блок active скрыт');
    }
    block_show = false;
  }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  scrollTracking();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  scrollTracking();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="active">Active</div>
```

Comment: `несколько таких блоков` - вы имеете ввиду несколько разных классов, или же это все идентификаторы id?

Comment: и `получить id показываемого блока`, вы имеете ввиду атрибут id у идентификатора, или дочерний номер блока в родительском контейнере?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Одинаковый классов , у которые разные id, при этом они добавляются путем ajax пагинации

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите отслеживать ID текущего блока, который находиться в области видимости, то:

```js
let block_show = null
let current_block_id = null

function scrollTracking() {
  const wt = $(window).scrollTop()
  const wh = $(window).height()
  const active = $(".active")
  const et = active.offset().top
  const eh = active.outerHeight()

if (wt + wh >= et && wt + wh - eh * 2 <= et + (wh - eh)) {
    if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
      console.log("Блок active в области видимости")
    }
    block_show = true
    current_block_id = active.attr("id")
    console.log("ID: " + current_block_id)
  } else {
    if (block_show == null || block_show == true) {
      console.log("Блок active скрыт")
    }
    block_show = false
    current_block_id = null
  }
}

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  scrollTracking()
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  scrollTracking()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="active" id="id12345">Active</div>
```

Comment: А если  id="idХХХ" таких блоков много, как быть?